# Dropbox v2 API: Is there any way to get the original mixed-case path of/from a file?

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

The `FileMetadata` type has the property `path_lower`... but I want the original mixed-case path. Is there any way to get it with the v2 API?

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/204135253-Any-way-to-get-mixed-case-path-for-a-file- ]

Answer (score 1):

Update: @Greg wrote in a comment below:

> the FileMetadata object now contains a "path_display" property

so the below is now obsolete.

---

As revealed by @Greg in [the corresponding thread in the Dropbox Community site](https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/204135253-Any-way-to-get-mixed-case-path-for-a-file-), this is technically possible but only indirectly and inefficiently:

> `FileMetadata.name` will contain the case-preserved name, so you would need to build the path up from that.

In other words, walk back up the directory hierarchy in the path, making a HTTP request for each parent directory, in order to get its mixed-case name, and then reassemble the full mixed-case path from all of those names.

While this is feasible, it’s not what I was after — I was hoping there might be some (possibly undocumented) way to request that the full mixed-case path be provided as a field in `FileMetadata` values, without making additional requests — or perhaps by making max 1 additional request.

Oh well. Greg did write:

> I’ll send this along as a feature request to the team though.

So my fingers are crossed.

Comment: Quick update, the FileMetadata object now contains a "path_display" property. You can read more about it in the [documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-get_metadata).